# Re-run failed android tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Is there a way to run only the failed set of tests on Android using Gradle?

At the moment, I run my tests as follows.

```
./gradle connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

There are tests that occasionally fail due to environment issues which are difficult to control and what I would like to do is be able to only run those failed tests and merge the result with the previous test results.

So for example, if I have 100 tests and 90 succeed, I would like to re-run the failing 10 tests.  If those 10 pass the second time around, I would like to merge those results with the original test run.

It looks like this has been discussed several times for Gradle but there doesn't seem to be a solution yet.

```
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4068
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4450
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1283
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason they don't have a way to only rerun failed tests is because it screws up the way Gradle currently works. This happens because on the first run, Gradle knows 90 tests passed. If you update the code, and then rerun only the 10 failed tests (using this new option you want them to add), then Gradle would think that all the tests have passed. However, this isn't the case because the tests which previously passed might've broken from the update which fixed the failing tests.

Despite this, the problem has been solved. Gradle reruns failed tests first, and provides a `--fail-fast` flag for the `test` task. This effectively does what you want (i.e., only reruns failed tests).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *automatically* rerun failed tests as part of the same build in which they failed, and succeed the build if they succeed on retry, you can use the [Test Retry](https://github.com/gradle/test-retry-gradle-plugin) Gradle plugin.  This will rerun each failed test a certain number of times, with the option of failing the build if too many failures have occurred overall.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.test-retry' version '1.2.0'
}

test {
    retry {
        maxRetries = 3
        maxFailures = 20 // Optional attribute
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin does not support android instrumented tests..
https://github.com/gradle/test-retry-gradle-plugin/issues/17